# I'm trying to automate my swim team's event list

Tags: google-sheets

We used to do everything on paper, now I have a basic sheet that saves a lot of time but is still not very efficient and could be improved. The link is to an image of a simplified sheet. We input our athletes into the lineups (left) and then again into an event list (right) after that the event list auto fills event cards (not pictured) is there a way to make the event list auto fill with all three columns? I'm a relative newbie at sheets so maybe it's easier than I think.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/K2frjcJQjNoMVr8s5

Comment: Please share a link to the sample spreadsheet shown in the image. An image may help for understanding, but it doesn't allow any easily reproducible or accessible data to work with. That would then require that the volunteer contributors here start their own spreadsheet and hand-enter your data before they could even begin to consider, build and then test a solution. Help us help you: share a link to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to my example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199bb9ao3hSNTJtX8ttK_IVqUPXNTf5fqlNJZUuZUIlk/edit?usp=sharing

(Also before going to my solution, just like Erik said, include a link next time. It makes it much easier to help you.)

[image]

You may notice that there is an additional table there. That's the main solution, my solution anyways. You can hide it or place is somewhere else so that it's not such an eyesore.

```
={FLATTEN(B2:D12),
 FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A12 & ",",3)),","))),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("LANE 1,LANE 2,LANE 3,", COUNTA(A2:A)), ","))}
```

Within F2, the formula above resides.

```
=FILTER(F2:H,NOT(ISBLANK(F2:F)))
```

And within J2 is the one above.

#### Explanation

This one took a while to figure out, and I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do it. The performance on my device seems adequate; there aren't any random lag spikes when changing values.

F2 contains an array. Arrays are made using curly brackets. The first column within the array is simply all the values within B2 down to D12 made into one column, including the blanks. This is important for later. Second column has a formula that takes `A1:A12` and duplicates it 3 times. I'm not even exactly sure what I did, since I was in a flurry when making that one. Third column simply repeats the string "LANE 1 LANE 2 LANE 3" as many times as there values in column A.

Finally J2. J2's formula simply filters out all blanks in the F column and returns only those that have value.

#### Things to note

You may notice that my dataset is not the same as yours. This all still work, but there are modifications to be done.

In the first formula (F2), you will need to change the ranges `B2:D12` to the correct range, `B2:D37`. Change accordingly if you add or remove more events. Change `A2:A12` similarly.

In the other formula (J2), just make sure that when you move the table, you also change the reference accordingly.